# Tensorflow Input Shapes Incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow

Trying to build a Tensorflow model where my data has 70 features. Here is the setup of my first layer:

`tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=50, activation='relu', input_shape=(None,70)),`

Setting the input shape to `(None,70)` seemed best to me as I am using a feed forward neural network where each "row" of data is unique. I am using a batch size (for now) of size 10. Should my input shape change to `(10,70)`??

I have tried with the original `(None, 70)` and gotten the error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, None, 70) for input Tensor("dense_33_input:0", shape=(None, None, 70), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (10, 70).

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float64 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.
```

Quite confused on exactly what is going wrong with the `input_shape` as `(None, 70)` seems to fit the best. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Wanted to add a reproducible example for more context. Sorry for the length. This is a reproduction of [this example][1] to better suit my current data (non-image).

**Variational Autoencoder Model**

```
class VAE(tf.keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(VAE, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=50, activation='relu', input_shape=(70,)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim + latent_dim), #No activation
        ])
        
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=50, activation='relu', input_shape=(latent_dim,)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=70),
        ])
        
    @tf.function
    def sample(self, eps=None):
        if eps is None:
            eps = tf.random.normal(shape=(100, self.latent_dim))
        return self.decode(eps, apply_sigmoid=True)

    def encode(self, x):
        mean, logvar = tf.split(self.encoder(x), num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
        return mean, logvar

    def reparameterize(self, mean, logvar):
        eps = tf.random.normal(shape=mean.shape)
        return eps * tf.exp(logvar * .5) + mean

    def decode(self, z, apply_sigmoid=False):
        logits = self.decoder(z)
        if apply_sigmoid:
            probs = tf.sigmoid(logits)
            return probs
        return logits


  [1]: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae
```

**Optimizer & Loss Funx**

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)

def log_normal_pdf(sample, mean, logvar, raxis=1):
    log2pi = tf.math.log(2. * np.pi)
    return tf.reduce_sum(
        -.5 * ((sample - mean) ** 2. * tf.exp(-logvar) + logvar + log2pi), axis=raxis)

def compute_loss(model, x):
    mean, logvar = model.encode(x)
    z = model.reparameterize(mean, logvar)
    x_logit = model.decode(z)
    cross_ent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=x_logit, labels=x)
    logpx_z = -tf.reduce_sum(cross_ent, axis=[1])
    logpz = log_normal_pdf(z, 0, 0)
    logqz_x = log_normal_pdf(z, mean, logvar)
    return -tf.reduce_mean(logpx_z + logpz - logqz_x)

@tf.function
def train_step(model, x, optimizer):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = compute_loss(model, x)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

**Train**

```
X = tf.random.uniform((100,70))
y = tf.random.uniform((100,))

ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))

tf.random.set_seed(1)

train = ds_train.shuffle(buffer_size=len(X))
train = train.batch(batch_size=10, drop_remainder=False)

epochs = 5
latent_dim = 2

model = VAE(2)

for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
    start_time = time.time()
    for i, (train_x, train_y) in enumerate(train):
        train_step(model, train_x, optimizer)
    end_time = time.time()
    
    loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
    for i, (test_x, test_y) in enumerate(ds_test):
        loss(compute_loss(model, test_x))
    elbo = -loss.result()
    display.clear_output(wait=False)
    print('Epoch: {}, Test set ELBO: {}, time elapse for current epoch: {}'
         .format(epoch, elbo, end_time - start_time))
```

Comment: Can you please define `X_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: Sorry...should be fixed now. `y` is unnecessary in this example.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with your example, and I ran into other errors. Can you please fix your example? Try running it in a fresh python interpreter (no variables already defined). Without an example, it will be difficult to help.

Comment: @jakub just made minor changes to `y` and the axis on reduce_sum. Should be to the same error I have

Comment: Thanks. Can you try changing `logpz = log_normal_pdf(z, 0., 0.)` to `logpz = log_normal_pdf(z, 0., 0.)` ? That will make those zeros floats instead of integer. I ran into the error that `tf.exp` cannot take int32.

Comment: Had just tried that and that fixes my problem. Thanks for helping me narrow it down. If you'll add to your answer I will gladly give you credit.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input_shape` should not include the batch dimension. Use `input_shape=(70,)`.

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=50, activation='relu', input_shape=(70,))
```

You can set the batch size when you call `model.fit(..., batch_size=10)`. See the documentation on [`tf.keras.Model.fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).

There was another error in the original post, due to passing an `int32` value to `tf.math.exp`. That line should should read

```
logpz = log_normal_pdf(z, 0., 0.)
```

to solve that error. Note the `0.` values, which evaluate to floats instead of ints.

Comment: Still getting the last error: `TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float64 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.` Can share more code if that is helpful...

Comment: Yes, please update your post with a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Just did...let me know your thoughts. Thanks